# Dynamic Strings and Xml

Tags: android, xml

I'm new to Android (and surely I'm not an expert Java developer), so I'm sorry for the dumb question

I would like to "capture" the id of a textView and to set its text value dynamically,
here is how I'm trying to do this:

```
public class AndStringTestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

String abc = "abcabc";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
    tv.setText(abc);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

and here is the Xml from which i'm reading the id of the textview i would like to write inside

```
// main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/test"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

the error i receive is the usual `Application stopped unexpectedly`

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Call setContentView before trying to find the TextView. The TextView does not exist before you have called setContentView (which will inflate your XML layout)

Answer (score 3):

Call `setContentView(R.layout.main)` before you call `findViewById()`.